# WordPress User Registration/ Sign Up -> Able to take Paid Certification Courses & keep track of Completed Certificates

Tags: plugins, security, user-registration, authentication, oauth

I'm really new to WordPress and been tasked with this assignment and not sure how to tackle it.

So we have a WordPress site and we plan on using the Masteriyo plugin to create and sell online certifications (it's a medical non-profit, sounds scammy but I assure you its not).

We want it so the users of our page has to register and sign in before having access to our Courses Page.

...

So, few options I was considering:

A) using/ paying for the "User Registration" Plugin by WPEverest

B) integrating OAuth2 (is it possible to create Schemas with WordPress? Would like to show what certifications they have completed)

C) redirecting users to our own (not WordPress) site with the form, then redirecting them back to our WordPress certifications page

...

What are the pros and cons, and what method would you take?

My lead wants to do option C, create our own form, but I am concerned with potential vulnerability and security issues, and the amount of nuanced work like forget your password link and creating a profile page where they can see their certifications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to go about doing this but I don't think you need to redirect people away from the site.  I don't know what the Masteriyo plugin is and since it's the content from that plugin you're looking to obfuscate, you should inquire with them.  Questions like this are subjective and hard to give a definitive answer for.  (Have you looked at Sensei LMS by WordPress/Auttomatic? It should do almost everything you've asked above right out the box and also integrates directly with WooCommerce and WooCommerce Members.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.